# Encrypting/decrypting some file types with Rijndael 256 (CakePHP Security library) garbles contents

Tags: security, cakephp, encryption, encoding, rijndael

I am using CakePHP's `Security::rijndael()` function to encrypt and decrypt text and files.  I previously wrote some code using `mcrypt` directly, which worked in the same way, but then I found `Security::rijndael` and realised I had reinvented the wheel.  So the problem I have happens either way.

If I encrypt a string, or a text file, or a PDF document, the code below works perfectly and I get the correct decrypted string/file.  However, if I try encrypting a .doc, .docx or an image file, the decrypted file is garbled.

Here's the code that does the encrypting/decrypting

```
public static function encrypt($plainText, $key) {
    $plainText = base64_encode($plainText);

    //Hash key to ensure it is long enough
    $hashedKey = Security::hash($key);
    $cipherText = Security::rijndael($plainText, $hashedKey, 'encrypt');
    return base64_encode($cipherText);
}

public static function decrypt($cipherText, $key) {
    $cipherText = base64_decode($cipherText);

    $hashedKey = Security::hash($key);
    $plainText = Security::rijndael($cipherText, $hashedKey, 'decrypt');
    return base64_decode($plainText);
}
```

...and this code actually presents the file to the user (I've edited the code to keep it simple):

```
public function download($id){
    App::uses('File', 'Utility');
    $key = $this->User->getDocumentKey($id);
    $file = new File('my_encrypted_file.docx');
    $encrypted = $file->read();
    $decrypted = Encrypt::decrypt($encrypted, $key);

    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_decrypted_file.docx"');
    echo $decrypted;
    die();
}
```

**Update** - it appears that the encryption is a red herring, as the file is garbled even without encrypting and decrypting it!  The following produces exactly the same broken file:

```
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.docx"');
        $file = new File($this->data['Model']['file']['tmp_name']);
        echo $file->read();
        die();
```

Comment: `the decrypted file is garbled`: does that mean you just can't open it or do the bytes completely differ from what the should be? Possibly `rijndael()` leaves some padding or adds (or removes) a null-byte at the end of the decrypted data.

Comment: The .docx, for example, starts with: PK##########!#M."��###�#######[Content_Types].xml.  Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: That seems correct. (checked a valid .docx and it looked the same) Does it look different before encryption? What are the last few bytes of the file?

Comment: Hmmm... if I open the file in vim the last few characters are ^@^@^@^@.  Is that helpful? :S  I will check the doc before encryption now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was barking up the wrong tree.

For whatever reason (whitespace at the start of some PHP file maybe?), adding `ob_clean();` immediately after sending the headers, has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the reason for that problem now, it is [line `208` in `Security.php`](http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/cakephp/cakephp-2.3.0-beta/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php):

```
$out .= rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt($algorithm, $cryptKey, $text, $mode, $iv), "\0");
```

Since PHP's `mycrypt()` uses `ZeroBytePadding` this line removes the padding afterwards.

The problem is that a `.docx`-File (as far as I could check it) terminates with a few `Null`-characters. If you only remove a single one of them, *Word* fails to open the file.
So what happens is that `rtrim()` also deletes these bytes even though they are not part of the padding.

To fix this, you can add a termination character (for example `X`) at the end of your files before encrypting and remove it after decrypting. This will prevent cutting off the tailing zero-bytes from the `.docx`-files:

```
public static function encrypt($plainText, $key) {
    $plainText = base64_encode($plainText . "X"); // `X` terminates the file
    /* do encryption */
}

public static function decrypt($cipherText, $key) {
    /* do decrytion */
    return rtrim(base64_decode($plainText), "X"); // cut off the termination `X`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it hasn't worked though unfortunately - the files are still garbled.

Comment: Could you maybe somehow determine which parts of your file exactly are garbled?

Comment: See my edit - it looks like the encryption is not actually the issue!